# Webistrano git issue

Tags: git, capistrano, webistrano

I'm migrating my capistrano setup into webistrano and keep getting this error when I run any deployment commands:

executing locally:

```
 git ls-remote git@github.com:REPO.git HEAD
 Could not save revision: Unable to resolve revision for 'HEAD' on repository 'REPO_ADDRESSS'
```

My capistrano setup has the same params and works no problem from the command line. Can't seen to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: I got the same error, then I realized that I din't pushed my source code to the remote repo...hope this helps